# Using gulp-rtlclass with laravel-elixir

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I am working as a front-end developer on a Laravel prodject.
I always use gulp to generate rtl-CSS files which you can find [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rtlcss)

The issue is on Laravel there is a package called `elixir` that manages the gulp tasks,

for example using **gulp**:

```
gulp.task('task-name', function () {
 return gulp.src('source-files') // Get source files with gulp.src
 .pipe(gulp.dest('destination')) // Outputs the file in the    destination folder
})
```

the same example with **elixir**

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass([source-files], 'destination');
  });
```

I wan't to use **gulp-rtlclass** which is not supported or I can't find it in **elixir**

**what I have tried**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rtlcss = require('gulp-rtlcss');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src('css/*/css')
        .pipe(rtlcss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

and

```
elixir(function(mix) {
 mix.styles('css/*/css', 'public/css/')
 .pipe(rtlcss());
});
```

but both of them doesn't work

Please any ideas on how I can use  **gulp-rtlclass** with **laravel-elixir**

**Note:** I am using *laravel 5.2*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [laravel-elixir-rtl](https://github.com/pi0/laravel-elixir-rtl) extension that does exactly what you want.

Usage:

Install npm package

```
npm install --save laravel-elixir-rtl
```

Require extension

```
require('laravel-elixir-rtl');
```

Use in elixir mix pipes

```
mix.rtl('public/css/app.css', 'public/css/rtl');
```